# How can I contact Gmail support team?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-for-work

I've been trying to contact the Gmail support team. I'm a paying customer, using their Gmail for small business.

I cannot in the life of me figure out how one can contact them (by email or phone). I do not live in the US.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The numbers are pretty visible on Google App's [Get Support](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/static.py?page=contacting_support.html) page

> Business and Education editions, 7 days a week, 24 hours a day
>
> **Available for [system critical event](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=181632) emergencies**
>
> U.S. Technical Support: 1-877-355-5787
>
> International Technical Support: 1-404-978-9282
>
> [Email support](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/request.py?contact_type=cuf&premium=1)

Comment: these numbers are not reachable from where I live. Very strange. No other way to contact them (email let's say?)

Comment: @vondip Email like is given.

Comment: @vondip You're welcome, best wishes!